# apache POI + nifi +ExecuteGroovyScript : groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi, inputstream

I try to get my input file (which is an xlsm file) into an ExecuteGroovyScript nifi processor.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.*
import java.nio.charset.*
import java.io.*

def flowFile = session.get()

if (!flowFile) return

try {
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, { InputStream in, OutputStream out ->

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(in);
   
    } as StreamCallback)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} catch (e) {
    log.error('Something went wrong', e)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

And I got this error:

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for:   java.io.FileInputStream(org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.io.TaskTerminationInputStream)

Because of this line: `FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(in);`

it looks like it's considering my inputstream as a terminationtask. but I saw this way in a lot of codes and can't figure why it doesn't want to take my inputStream properly.
Any help?

Comment: FileInputStream constructor could take only filename, file, or file descriptor as a parameter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Comment: how POI related to your question?

Comment: The next step after importing the input file will be :
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
i tried also Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream) but i got a outOfMemory error.

Comment: `WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream)` this i a right way. out of memory  - so, you have to increase memory limits for nifi in `conf/bootstrap.conf` file. you could try to write flow file into a physical file and then create workbook based on fileinputstream

Comment: I increased the memory a lot and it worked..